Auth0 Failed With Status 400
I am trying to create users from ASP.NET Core 5 Web API project for Auth0, was going through this official doc to make it work - Create User. Everything looks good through I am continuously getting the status code 400 and from the doc, the status code may indicate the followings:
400 - Invalid request body. The message will vary depending on the cause.
400 - Connection does not support user creation through the API. It must either be a database or passwordless connection.
400 - Cannot set username for connection without requires_username.
400 - Connection does not exist.
400 - Connection is disabled.

I've the connection name as Username-Password-Authentication and in the code snippet used it as follows according to the doc:
var content = new StringContent("{\"email\":\"sample1234@yahoo.com\",\"phone_number\":\"\",\"user_metadata\":{},\"blocked\":false,\"email_verified\":false,\"phone_verified\":false,\"app_metadata\":{},\"given_name\":\"sample12\",\"family_name\":\"sample12\",\"name\":\"sample12\",\"nickname\":\"sample12\",\"picture\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"\",\"connection\":\"NewDbConn-2024\",\"password\":\"\",\"verify_email\":false,\"username\":\"sample-2024\"}", null, "application/json");

Here's the full code:
[HttpPost("CreateUserAuth0")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUserAuth0()
{
    // 
    // Add authorization access token.
    string accessToken = _auth0Service.GetAccessToken();
    string authorization = $"Bearer {accessToken}";
   
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://company-domain.us.auth0.com/api/v2/users");
    
    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    request.Headers.Add("authorization", authorization);

    var content = new StringContent("{\"email\":\"sample1234@yahoo.com\",\"phone_number\":\"\",\"user_metadata\":{},\"blocked\":false,\"email_verified\":false,\"phone_verified\":false,\"app_metadata\":{},\"given_name\":\"sample12\",\"family_name\":\"sample12\",\"name\":\"sample12\",\"nickname\":\"sample12\",\"picture\":\"\",\"user_id\":\"\",\"connection\":\"NewDbConn-2024\",\"password\":\"\",\"verify_email\":false,\"username\":\"sample-2024\"}", null, "application/json");
    request.Content = content;
    
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
 
    return Ok(response.Content);
}

I am not sure if there's anything that I am missing in the body or even the connection name, though the connection is created in the dashboard.
One more thing, is there any way that I can send the request with an object rather than the one used above? As as example, like this:
return new CreateUserAuth0
{
   Email = user.Email,
   Blocked = false,
   EmailVerified = true,
   PhoneVerified = false,
   GivenName = user.FirstName,
   FamilyName = user.LastName,
   Name = user.FirstName,
   Connection = "NewDbConn-2024",
   Password = "",
   VerifyEmail = false,
   Username = user.Email
};

Connection: Image provided

Update 1 - Here are the steps that I did to create a new connection, provided with screenshots:
Step 1: Created the connection NewDbConn-2024

Step 2:

Step 3:

Step 4:

Step 5:

Step 6:


Can you verify what string accessToken = _auth0Service.GetAccessToken(); returns? 400 HTTP errors are generally 'you failed to provide a valid request', and my prime suspect would be 401/403 - authorization error.

Access token is fine I believe, previously for that I received status code 415 - Unsupported media type @orhtej2. Later it was fixed.

Most likely your body content is wrong. Don't submit StringContent like that, try use https://flurl.dev/, you will avoid lots of bugs.

The error states several reasons why the request is/may be invalid. Have you checked the connection you have created for each of those reasons.

Connection is created @phuzi. I guess, it's the request body. Though not sure.

I am assuming so @Rosdi Kasim.

There are many example on [so] of using objects instead of manually created JSON and it certainly doesn't require an additional package.

It probably isn't enough that the connection exists, it sounds like it needs to be configured appropriately. Can you include that configuration in your question too

A screenshot is provided as reference for the connection @phuzi.

That doesn't show how the connection is configured though!

Can you see the updated post @phuzi? I've created a new connection, provided in the post with screenshots. Though it didn't work, any suggestion you would like to provide.

Can you see the updated post @orhtej2? Any suggestion you would like to provide.

Can you see the updated post @Rosdi Kasim? Any suggestion you would like to provide.

Judging from your screenshots it may be the case of 400 Cannot set username for connection without requires_username. (Requires username is unchecked on your screenshot).

I get this exception each time - {"Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)."} @orhtej2. I am not sure if I am close enough to get it done.

Got it working. When the request gets submitted, it doesn't process data with null, in my case these two were the issues - \"user_metadata\":{} and \"app_metadata\":{}.
